# Onclick Event - Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to have a click event on < tr > tag of my table that's dynamically generated. 
While registering event for 1st time, there is no exception.
But Function is not being called if I click on tablerow.

I tried getElementById also, which is even giving extra exception while registering on click event.

Please help.

Below is part of my code:

Script:

```
$("#empName").on("click", function(){
        alert("Hi");
    });
```

HTML:

```
$(obj).find('#abc tr:last').after("<tr class='odd' id='empName'><td>"+emp+"<br/>"+eventName+"</br>"+ind+"</br>"+loc +"</td></tr>");
```

Comment: First..Instead of doing `$("empName")`.. do `$("#empName")`

Comment: jQuery version used?

Comment: I think jquery < 1.7 is used.. then `.on()` won't be available try `.bind()`

Comment: @Pratik Better would be if you can share a fiddle...

Comment: @ArunPJohny: If on not available,it should throw exception while registering event , isn't it?

Comment: @Pratik then are you sure that the event registration part is causing the error...

Comment: @Pratik yes... then when is the error coming

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Would you please check question again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
$("#abc #empName").on("click", function(){
    alert("Hi");
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Lepanto: It worked :) But I am not sure why my code should not work..! Can you please explain?

Comment: @Pratik If you use dynamic(live) contact you cannot catch event without on

Comment: @SelVaa: I have also used on here....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(document).on("click","#empName", function(){
        alert("Hi");
    });
```